NDSolve numerical instability for a system of PDEs
I'm trying to use NDSolve to solve a system of three coupled PDEs. I've tried using many different methods but I get numerical instability with everything. If I increase the time (tend) then the code breaks down. Does any one have any ideas how I can solve these please? Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks! Here is my code:
Clear["Global`*"]
G = 1;
M = 1;
alpha = 0.1;
Rin = 1;
Rout = 10;
HR = 0.1;
OmegaK = Sqrt[G M/R^3];
OmegaKout = Sqrt[G M/Rout^3];
cs = HR R OmegaK;
nu = alpha cs^2/OmegaK;

eq1 = R D[Sigma[R, t], t] + D[ R Sigma[R, t] vR [R, t] , R];
P = cs^2 Sigma[R, t];
eq2 =   D[vR[R, t], t] + 
   vR[R, t] D[vR[R, t], R] - ((Omega[R, t])^2 - OmegaK^2) R +  
   D[P, R]/Sigma[R, t];
eq3 =  D[R^2 Omega[R, t], t] + vR[R, t] D[R^2 Omega[R, t], R] -  
   1/(Sigma[R, t] R) D[nu Sigma[R, t] R^3 D[Omega[R, t], R], R];

Sigma0 = R^(-1);
Omegastar = 0.8;
Rjoin = (G M/Omegastar^2)^(1/3);
Omega0 = Piecewise[{{Omegastar, R < Rjoin}}, OmegaK];
vR0 = 1/(D[R^2 Omega0, R])/(R Sigma0) D[nu Sigma0 R^3 D[Omega0, R], R];

tend = 20;

sol = NDSolve[{
    eq1 == 0,
    eq2 == 0,
    eq3 == 0,
    Omega[R, 0] == Omega0,
    Sigma[R, 0] == Sigma0,
    vR[R, 0] == vR0,
    Omega[Rin, t] == Omegastar,
    Omega[Rout, t] == OmegaKout,
    Sigma[Rin, t] == 1,
    vR[Rout, t] == 0
    }, {Sigma, Omega, vR}, {R, Rin, Rout}, {t, 0, tend}];

p1 = Plot[{Sigma0,
   Sigma[R, t] /. sol /. t -> 0,
   Sigma[R, t] /. sol /. t -> tend/10,
   Sigma[R, t] /. sol /. t -> tend/2,
   Sigma[R, t] /. sol /. t -> tend}, {R, Rin, Rout}, PlotRange -> All,
   Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"R", "Sigma"}]
p2 = Plot[{Omega0,
   Omega[R, t] /. sol /. t -> 0,
   Omega[R, t] /. sol /. t -> tend/10,
   Omega[R, t] /. sol /. t -> tend/2,
   Omega[R, t] /. sol /. t -> tend}, {R, Rin, Rout}, PlotRange -> All,
   Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"R", "Omega"}]
p3 = Plot[{
   vR0,
   vR[R, t] /. sol /. t -> 0,
   vR[R, t] /. sol /. t -> tend/10,
   vR[R, t] /. sol /. t -> tend/2,
   vR[R, t] /. sol /. t -> tend}, {R, Rin, Rout}, PlotRange -> All, 
  Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"R", "vR"}]
```


It looks like acoustic waves generated due to nonsmoothed initial conditions.

Thank you very much for your reply. However, if I set Omega0=OmegaK and change Omegastar=1, then I still get the instability. Any ideas? Thanks!

Why do you think that the system should be stable with arbitrary manipulations of parameters? In general case this system can't be stable since it generates shock waves. It is not clear what solution are you looking for?

These equations model a star (that is rotating with frequency Omegastar) with an accretion disc. So ideally I would like to be able to change the stellar spin rate and model the time evolution of the disc.  I would also like to be able to change the initial surface density, Sigma.

It could be nice to add all restrictions for parameters to clear understanding of your problem.

To avoid acoustic waves generated by nonsmoothed initial data we need to extend region of computation up to Rout = 1000 as follows
Clear["Global`*"]
G = 1;
M = 1;
alpha = 0.1;
Rin = 1;
Rout = 1000;
HR = 0.1;
OmegaK = Sqrt[G M/R^3];
OmegaKout = Sqrt[G M/Rout^3];
cs = HR R OmegaK;
nu = alpha cs^2/OmegaK; 

eq1 = R D[Sigma[R, t], t] + D[R Sigma[R, t] vR[R, t], R];
P = cs^2 Sigma[R, t];
eq2 = D[vR[R, t], t] + 
   vR[R, t] D[vR[R, t], R] - ((Omega[R, t])^2 - OmegaK^2) R + 
   D[P, R]/Sigma[R, t];
eq3 = D[R^2 Omega[R, t], t] + vR[R, t] D[R^2 Omega[R, t], R] - 
   1/(Sigma[R, t] R) D[nu Sigma[R, t] R^3 D[Omega[R, t], R], R];

Sigma0 = R^(-1);
Omegastar = 0.8;
Rjoin = (G M/Omegastar^2)^(1/3);
Omega0 = Piecewise[{{Omegastar, R < Rjoin}}, OmegaK];
vR0 = 1/(D[R^2 Omega0, R])/(R Sigma0) D[nu Sigma0 R^3 D[Omega0, R], R];

tend = 100;

sol = NDSolve[{eq1 == 0, eq2 == 0, eq3 == 0, Omega[R, 0] == Omega0, 
    Sigma[R, 0] == Sigma0, vR[R, 0] == vR0, 
    Omega[Rin, t] == Omegastar, Omega[Rout, t] == OmegaKout, 
    Sigma[Rin, t] == 1, vR[Rout, t] == 0}, {Sigma, Omega, vR}, {R, Rin, 
    Rout}, {t, 0, tend}];

Visualization
{p1 = Plot[
   Evaluate@
    Table[Sigma[R, t] /. sol, {t, {0, tend/10, tend/2, tend}}], {R, 
    Rin, Rout}, PlotRange -> All, Frame -> True, 
   PlotLegends -> 
    Table[Row[{"t = ", t}], {t, {0, tend/10, tend/2, tend}}], 
   FrameLabel -> {"R", "Sigma"}],
 p2 = Plot[
   Evaluate@
    Table[Omega[R, t] /. sol, {t, {0, tend/10, tend/2, tend}}], {R, 
    Rin, Rout}, PlotRange -> All, Frame -> True, 
   PlotLegends -> 
    Table[Row[{"t = ", t}], {t, {0, tend/10, tend/2, tend}}], 
   FrameLabel -> {"R", "Omega"}],
 p3 = Plot[
   Evaluate@
    Table[vR[R, t] /. sol, {t, {0, tend/10, tend/2, tend}}], {R, Rin, 
    Rout}, PlotRange -> All, Frame -> True, 
   PlotLegends -> 
    Table[Row[{"t = ", t}], {t, {0, tend/10, tend/2, tend}}], 
   FrameLabel -> {"R", "vR"}]}


Update 1. We can damper acoustic waves using artificial viscosity and method of lines with "StiffnessSwitching" option as follows
Clear["Global`*"]
G = 1;
M = 1;
alpha = 0.1;
Rin = 1;
Rout = 20;
HR = 0.1;
OmegaK = Sqrt[G M/R^3];
OmegaKout = Sqrt[G M/Rout^3];
cs = HR R OmegaK;
nu = alpha cs^2/OmegaK; mu = 2 10^-2; mu1 = 5 10^-2;

eq1 = D[Sigma[R, t], t] + D[R Sigma[R, t] vR[R, t], R]/R - 
   mu1 D[Sigma[R, t], R, R];
P = cs^2 Sigma[R, t];
eq2 = D[vR[R, t], t] + 
   vR[R, t] D[vR[R, t], R] - ((Omega[R, t])^2 - OmegaK^2) R + 
   D[P, R]/Sigma[R, t] - mu D[vR[R, t], R, R];
eq3 = D[R^2 Omega[R, t], t] + vR[R, t] D[R^2 Omega[R, t], R] - 
   1/(Sigma[R, t] R) D[nu Sigma[R, t] R^3 D[Omega[R, t], R], R];

Sigma0 = R^(-1);
Omegastar = 0.8;
Rjoin = (G M/Omegastar^2)^(1/3);
appro = With[{k = 100}, ArcTan[k #]/Pi + 1/2 &];
Omega0 = 
  Simplify`PWToUnitStep@
    Piecewise[{{Omegastar, R < Rjoin}, {OmegaK, True}}] /. 
   UnitStep -> appro;
vR0 = 1/(D[R^2 Omega0, R])/(R Sigma0) D[nu Sigma0 R^3 D[Omega0, R], R];

tend = 200;

sol = NDSolve[{eq1 == 0, eq2 == 0, eq3 == 0, Omega[R, 0] == Omega0, 
    Sigma[R, 0] == Sigma0, vR[R, 0] == vR0, 
    Omega[Rin, t] == Omega0 /. R -> Rin, 
    Omega[Rout, t] == Omega0 /. R -> Rout, 
    Sigma[Rin, t] == Sigma0 /. R -> Rin, 
    vR[Rout, t] == vR0 /. R -> Rout, 
    Derivative[1, 0][vR][Rout, t] == 0, 
    Derivative[1, 0][Sigma][Rout, t] == D[Sigma0, R] /. 
     R -> Rout}, {Sigma, Omega, vR}, {R, Rin, Rout}, {t, 0, tend}, 
   Method -> {"MethodOfLines", 
     "DifferentiateBoundaryConditions" -> {True, "ScaleFactor" -> 1}, 
     Method -> "StiffnessSwitching"}, InterpolationOrder -> All];

Visualization
{p1 = Plot[
   Evaluate@
    Table[Sigma[R, t] /. sol, {t, {0, tend/10, tend/2, tend}}], {R, 
    Rin, Rout}, PlotRange -> All, Frame -> True, 
   PlotLegends -> 
    Table[Row[{"t = ", t}], {t, {0, tend/10, tend/2, tend}}], 
   FrameLabel -> {"R", "Sigma"}],
 p2 = Plot[
   Evaluate@
    Table[Omega[R, t] /. sol, {t, {0, tend/10, tend/2, tend}}], {R, 
    Rin, Rout}, PlotRange -> All, Frame -> True, 
   PlotLegends -> 
    Table[Row[{"t = ", t}], {t, {0, tend/10, tend/2, tend}}], 
   FrameLabel -> {"R", "Omega"}],
 p3 = Plot[
   Evaluate@
    Table[vR[R, t] /. sol, {t, {0, tend/10, tend/2, tend}}], {R, Rin, 
    Rout}, PlotRange -> All, Frame -> True, 
   PlotLegends -> 
    Table[Row[{"t = ", t}], {t, {0, tend/10, tend/2, tend}}], 
   FrameLabel -> {"R", "vR"}]}



Thanks again! Unfortunately I find that increasing the outer radius means that it isn't resolving the area of interest (the inner boundary region). If I increase MaxStepFraction up to 1/1000 then I still get the instability in that region. Any other ideas? Thank you again for your help.

@AstroB We can resolve this problem using implicit solver and artificial viscosity.  Please, note that this system is very sensitive to the initial data. In general case it generates shock waves after initial state decay.

@AstroB Please, see Update 1 with artificial viscosity.
